# When I try to install Ubuntu or any OS I get a fatal error (Executing 'grub-install /dev/mmcblk0' failed.)

Tags: grub2, partitioning

So whenever I try to install Ubuntu 15.04 / Ubuntu Mate / Linux Mint I get this fatal error: `Cannot install grub on /dev/mmcblk0: fatal error during installation`. I'm far from a Linux expert, I have hardly any experience myself, but from what I can find it should be installing onto /dev/sda1? This is quite stressful for me because I have no idea what I have done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I really am not an expert so simple English would also be appreciated.

(I installed the OS's onto the USB Flash Drives using Pendrivelinux on an old Windows PC.)

Comment: Is there more to the fatal error?

Comment: What is the target machine? What are the hardware specs? Is it a regular x86 PC? Is /dev/mmcblk some kind of flash storage?

Comment: The target machine is an Acer Aspire V5-171. Hardware specs are as follows: Processor: Intel Core I3-2377M running at 1.5ghz, Memory is 4GB DDR3, Screen size (probably irrelevant) 11.6", Graphics card Intel HD Graphics 3000, chipset: Intel HM77, from what I can remember from when I had windows 8.1 it is a regular x86 PC (notebook). I can't seem to figure out what /dev/mmcblk1 is but flash storage sounds like a good guess.

Comment: I have an update on the fatal error I'm getting. This is the exact wording of it: Executing 'grub-install /dev/mmcblk0' failed. This is a fatal error.

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/mmcblkX` means that it tried to install to partition on a flash device that does not use the SATA protocol. The Acer Aspire V5-171 however seems to have a SATA port and typical SATA storage. I suggest you use manual partitioning and check that the bootloader gets installed to the correct hard drive. It's the lower drop down box in the manual partitioning dialog.

[image]